# Recursive Java data structure - creating an array of a family tree

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

How do I create an efficient recursive function - that will take an input feed - which could be 1000's of rows long. Into a compacted array. The recursive function will need potentially some kind of lookup to determine if there is a manager above the current employee id.

I'm trying to build an application that may require an entire relationship management tree in an array.

I need to figure a method to create a recursive function over an input data feed to map it to collated output array.

```
//the input data may look something like this
[{
    "employeeId": "A1",
    "managerId": "B1",
    "employeeRole": "Sales0",
    "managerRole": "Sales1"
}, {
    "employeeId": "B1",
    "managerId": "C1",
    "employeeRole": "Sales1",
    "managerRole": "Sales2"
}, {
    "employeeId": "C1",
    "managerId": "D1",
    "employeeRole": "Sales2",
    "managerRole": "Sales3"
}, {
    "employeeId": "D1",
    "managerId": "",
    "employeeRole": "Sales3",
    "managerRole": "Sales4"
}]


//create a final output array like this
[
    "level1id": "A1",
    "level2id": "B1",
    "level3id": "C1",
    "level4id": "D1",
]
```

The bare bone pseduo code I have at this stage is something like this

```
void myMethod(String employeeId, String[] rawData, Map < String, String > dataMap) {

    //employeeId -- child id

    //rawData - from feed 

    //dataMap - the array being built to contain ALL relationships from grand child, parent, grandparent.



    getManager(employeeId, rawData) {

        //find the manager of the current employeeid

        //managerData[0] - manager id
        //managerData[1] - manager role

        return managerData;
    }


    managerData = getManager(employeeId, rawData);

    managerId = managerData[0];
    managerRole = managerData[1];

    dataMap.put(managerData[1], managerData[0]);
    // like [{"customerLevel1" : "SKDOL2"}]



    //if there is no manager id - the grandparent manager has been found
    if (managerId !== null)
        return;
    else {
        //this employeeid has a manager above them - loop through again until the grandparent is found (employee id with no manager) 
        myMethod(managerId, rawData, dataMap);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, that's a nice project. What's your question?

Comment: The question - is - how do I go about transforming the input data efficiently into a compacted array.

Comment: So say that in your question. You'll want to read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you haven't already; this is far too broad as it is, since you're just asking for us to provide you with code.

Comment: Yes - thank you for the pedantic comments - I have edited the post to re-enforce the question - I was focusing on the required logic at hand

Comment: It may also be worth changing the title - you are not looking for a recursive Java function, you are looking for a recursive Java data structure. This is not a pedantic statement, and n'or was @QPaysTaxes', this is a way of improving your question and therefore increasing the chance of you getting good answers.

Answer (score 1):

You have some work to do to read in the data and parse it and build your data structures but something like this for the class relationships look close to what you should need.

```
class Person {

    private final String id;

    public Person(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

}

class Employee extends Person {

    private final String managerId;

    public String getManagerId() {
        return managerId;
    }

    public Employee(String id, String managerId ) {
        super(id);
        this.managerId = managerId;
    }

}

class Manager extends Employee {

    private final String role;

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public Manager(String id, String managerId, String role ) {
        super(id, managerId);
        this.role = role;
    }

}

/**
 * Use this to look up any person. 
 * 
 * Put ALL employees an managers in here as you read them.
 */
Map<String, Employee> personLookup = new HashMap<>();
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume your input data format is json, so you will need the [json.jar](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/38084735/blog/werdna1222coldcodes/download/json.jar).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class OrgnizationTree {

    HashMap<String, ArrayList<Employee>> jsonDataMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Employee>>();
    HashMap<String, Employee> employeeMap = new HashMap<String, Employee>();
    Employee root;

    public void buildTree(String jsonData) throws Exception {
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonData);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject object = (JSONObject) array.get(i);
            String employeeId = object.get("employeeId").toString();
            String managerId = object.get("managerId").toString();
            if (managerId == null || managerId.isEmpty()) {
                root = new Employee(employeeId, null);
            } else {
                Employee subordinate = new Employee(employeeId);
                if (jsonDataMap.containsKey(managerId)) {
                    jsonDataMap.get(managerId).add(subordinate);
                } else {
                    ArrayList<Employee> subordinates = new ArrayList<Employee>();
                    subordinates.add(subordinate);
                    jsonDataMap.put(managerId, subordinates);
                }
            }
        }
        for (Employee subordinate : jsonDataMap.get(root.getId())) {
            root.addSubordinate(subordinate);
            subordinate.setManager(root);
            employeeMap.put(root.getId(), root);
            buildSubTree(subordinate);
        }
    }

    public void buildSubTree(Employee manager) {
        List<Employee> subordinates = jsonDataMap.get(manager.getId());
        if (subordinates != null) {
            for (Employee subordinate : subordinates) {
                subordinate.setManager(manager);
                manager.addSubordinate(subordinate);
                buildSubTree(subordinate);
            }
        }
        employeeMap.put(manager.getId(), manager);
    }

    public Employee getManager(String employeeId) {
        Employee employee = employeeMap.get(employeeId);
        Employee manager = employee.getManager();
        return manager;
    }

    public Employee getEmployee(String employeeId) {
        return employeeMap.get(employeeId);
    }

    public Employee getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    public class Employee {
        String id;
        Employee manager;
        List<Employee> subordinates;
        Integer level;

        Employee(String id, Employee manager) {
            this.id = id;
            this.manager = manager;
            if (manager == null) {
                level = 0;
            } else {
                level = manager.level + 1;
            }
        }

        Employee(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public void addSubordinate(Employee subordinate) {
            if (subordinates == null) {
                subordinates = new ArrayList<Employee>();
            }
            subordinates.add(subordinate);
        }

        public String getId() {
            return this.id;
        }

        public Employee getManager() {
            return manager;
        }

        public void setManager(Employee manager) {
            this.manager = manager;
            this.level = manager.level + 1;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String jsonData = "[{'employeeId': 'A1', 'managerId': 'B1'}, {'employeeId': 'B1', 'managerId': 'C1'}, "
                + "{'employeeId': 'C1', 'managerId': 'D1'}, {'employeeId': 'D1', 'managerId': ''}]";
        OrgnizationTree t = new OrgnizationTree();
        t.buildTree(jsonData);
        System.out.println(t.getManager("A1").getId());
        System.out.println(t.getEmployee("A1").getManager().getId());
        System.out.println(t.getRoot().getId());
    }

}
```